# Bold text cancels the small caps format

Tags: bold, small-caps, text

I'm trying to put a text in small caps bold, but I'm noticing that as soon as I apply the bold, ovverrides the small caps rule. Isn't that in LaTex, these two rules don't live together?
This is my markup:

```
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\bf\textsc{Country List}} \\
```

I have also tried

```
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{\textsc{Country List}}} \\
```

and the result always remains this:

[image: Screenshot]

I hope it's nothing serious!

Comment: The Computer Modern fonts (the standard ones) don't feature bold small caps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` immediately below the `\documentclass` declaration.

Comment: Thank you @GuM! You Solve my life, that's the solution! :)

Comment: You’re welcome.  But you should be aware that adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` causes LaTeX to switch to a variant of Computer Modern fonts that does have a bold small caps shape, but also has sligthly different metrics: you might find that now (La)TeX chooses different linebreaks than before.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, thanks for the warning! ;)

Comment: Don't use `\bf` in LaTeX.

Comment: No, I won't use it!

Comment: @Memmo With MathJaX you can use it :-). Greetings from Sicily.

Comment: @Sebastiano hai ragione, ma per adesso non ne ho necessità ;)